# Guzzle POST request returns 500 error - php

Tags: php, httpresponse, php-curl, guzzle-service-description

Whenever I call the API, I expect a response in the form of JSON object which contains all necessary payment processing information.

But get a response like this:

> 500 {"description":"Something went wrong","reason":"INTERNAL_ERROR"}

And when using Postman it worked fine.
Is the problem in the written code or in the server?

```
$httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(); 
try {
    $response = $httpClient->request('POST', 'https://atfawry.fawrystaging.com/ECommerceWeb/api/payments/charge', [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept'       => 'application/json'
        ],
        'body' => json_encode([
            'merchantCode' => $merchantCode,
            'customerName' => 'Gazy saleh',
            'customerMobile' => '01234567891',
            'customerEmail' => 'gazy3@yahio.com',
            'customerProfileId' => $merchant_cust_prof_id,
            'merchantRefNumber' => $merchantRefNumber,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currencyCode' => 'EGP',
            'language' => 'en-eg',
            'chargeItems' => [
                'itemId' => '687463b2d866bd66a',
                'description' => 'new order for test',
                'price' => $amount,
                'quantity' => '1'
            ],
            'debitMobileWalletNo'=> $debitMobileWalletNo,
            'signature' => $signature,
            'paymentMethod' => 'MWALLET',
            'description' => 'new order for test'
        ], true)
    ]);


} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException $e) {

    $response = $e->getResponse();
    
    $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    echo $response->getStatusCode() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $responseBodyAsString;
}

$response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$paymentStatus = $response['type']; // get response values
```

Comment: An error in the 500 range usually means something went wrong on the server. However, if you do get a valid response in Postman you must be doing something differently in your guzzle request. In that case the server should give a response in the 400 range, letting you know what is wrong with the request.

Comment: It's a server bug, but it's almost for sure triggered by an invalid request on your side. To make a simile, you call an API that makes divisions, you submit zero as divisor, and the server gets a division by zero crash because it failed to validate input. Try using [builtin JSON support](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).